# Determine P(A U ( B' U C')') given the following conditions

Tags: probability

Determine P(A U ( B' U C')') given the following conditions

1 a) P(A) = .5, A,B,C are mutually exclusive

b) P(A) = .5, P(A) = 2P(B ∩ C) = 3P(A ∩ B ∩ C)

c) P(A) = 0.5, P(B ∩ C) = 1/3, and P(A ∩ C) = 0.

d) P(A' ∩ (B' ∪ C
'
)) = 0.7.

```
 for a), I turned P(A U ( B' U C')') into P(A U (B ∩ C)) using deMorgan's law 
 and since A,B,C are mutually exclusive, then (B ∩ C) should be 0 and should simply 
 be equal to P(A) which is .5 


 for b), P(B ∩ C) = 1/4 and P(A ∩ B ∩ C) = 1/6. so..if i let (B ∩ C) = D, i did
 P(A U D) = P(A) + P(D) - P(A ∩ D) = 7/12 

 I'm stuck on both c and d and can't seem to find a way to approach this one. 
 Not sure which formulas I should be using. Have I been correct for a and b though?
```

Comment: oops for part b) in the question, i meant to say P(A) = 2P(B ∩ C)

Comment: sanity check for b): probabilities are never greater than $1$

Comment: @angryavian that should be 7/12. my mistake. Looks like i made an addition error :^)

Answer (score 0):

a) and b) are correct.

c) (same approach as part b) $$P(A \cup (B \cap C))=P(A)+P(B\cap C)-P(A \cap B \cap C)=P(A)+P(B \cap C)$$

d) Apply deMorgan's law
$$(A' \cap (B' \cup C'))'=A \cup (B' \cup C')'$$

Comment: for b) how did you get rid of (A and B and C) ? is it because (a and c) = 0 so (A and B and C) = 0 as well?

Comment: @user125535 Yes, $A \cap B \cap C \subset A \cap C$ implies that $P(A \cap B \cap C) \le P(A \cap C)=0$.